# Google authentication error: invalid_request Missing required parameter: client_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make google authentication using **omniauth-google-oauth2** gem in my project and I've stumbled upon the following error when following the link **localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/**.

[image]

Why is that?

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

**config/secrets.yml**

```
development:
  secret_key_base: here_goes_my_secret_key_base
  google_client_id: 283155193283-8hnfdph0n4089iql70dh8g7428d258qc.apps.googleusercontent.com
  google_client_secret: xHnbKtackWe4D_1mrWTbRS9f

test:
  secret_key_base: here_goes_my_secret_key_base

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  google_client_id: <%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"] %>
  google_client_secret: <%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"] %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't look like your ENV-variable `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` is set, try this instead.

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id, Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret
end
```

The reason for your example not working is that you don't have the `ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]` set to any value. To set ENV-variables (in Linux) you can do any of the following on the console

```
export GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=my_client_id
```

This will however just set the variable in that session, to make this permanent you have to do edit your ~/.bash_profile

```
$ vi ~/.bash_proflle
```

And add the line above in that file.

**How do I access variables in `secrets.yml`?**

When you add information to the `config/secrets.yml` file they are accessed by using

```
Rails.application.secrets.my_key_name
```

**I want to store my ENV-variables in a YML file**

For this you can use the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Add the gem to your gemfile

```
gem "figaro"
```

Do bundle install

```
$ bundle exec figaro install
```

This will add the file `config/application.yml` (which you should add to your `.gitignore`)

In there you can add your ENV-variables

```
# config/application.yml

google_client_id: "this is my google id"
google_client_secret: "this is my client secret"
```

And after this you can access your client_id by just using

```
ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It solved the problem, however I don't get why this refused to work with the above example.

Comment: **secrets.yml** in my project is in `.gitignore`. Maybe it could have to do with this?

Comment: I added some more explanation to this :) 
secrets.yml should always be in .gitignore, You don't want your secret keys accessible in source control. When you deploy your app to production you should copy the secrets.yml file to the production servers.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you tons!

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow:

https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails/

After setup code, start the server using bellow command:

```
$ GOOGLE_KEY=yourgooglekey GOOGLE_SECRET=yourgooglesecret bundle exec rails s
```